# How do I check if Chef's version mets a gem requirement from inside a recipe?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, chef-infra, chef-recipe

Chef::Version contains the version number of the Chef gem, and I want to check that it meets the gem requirement of `~> 10.14` inside a recipe.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Alternatively, you can use Chef’s built-in version comparison mechanisms (available since at least Chef 12):

```ruby
Chef::VersionConstraint.new('>= 14.0.0').include? Chef::VERSION
```

Comment: This should not be the accepted answer.  The Chef::VersionConstraint class is only applicable to testing versions of cookbooks, and it only accepts X.Y or X.Y.Z version constraints and will fail if we ever release prerelease versions of chef-client.  The Gem::Version/Gem::Requirement classes are the appropriate classes to use since Chef::VERSION is a gem version, not a cookbook version.

Comment: @lamont that’s _really_ good to know. Thanks for clarifying that!

Answer (score 6):

Use `Gem::Requirement` and `Gem::Version`:

```
Gem::Requirement.new("~> 10.14").satisfied_by?(Gem::Version.new(Chef::VERSION))
```

This returns a boolean value - true if `Chef::VERSION` satisfies `~> 10.14`.