# Ignoring recipes in run_list if Chef client version too old

Tags: chef-infra

I am writing some ohai plugins which depends on the [`chef-cookbooks/ohai`](https://github.com/chef-cookbooks/ohai) cookbook, which requires chef version >= 12.7.

Our infrastructure requires being able to add the recipes from my plugin cookbooks on nodes which go all the way back to 12.4. The recipes don't need to run, just to be in the standardized run_list.

Is there anyway I can specify either that the `ohai` cookbook should only be required if the Chef version >= 12.7 in metadata.rb? Or that the entire cookbook and its recipes should be ignored if the Chef version is too old.

Answer (score -1):

i think you can achieve it by using [`include_recipe`](https://docs.chef.io/recipes.html#include-recipes) in conjunction with [`metadata.rb`](https://docs.chef.io/config_rb_metadata.html#version-constraints)

```
# recipes/default.rb
include_recipe 'foo' if Gem::Version.new(Gem.loaded_specs['chef'].version.to_s) >= Gem::Version.new('12.4')

# metadata.rb
depends 'foo' if  Gem::Version.new(Gem.loaded_specs['chef'].version.to_s) >= Gem::Version.new('12.4')
```

i have never tried it, but feels like it worth checking.
i also remember that in the past, i could use `Chef::VERSION` within the recipes.

Comment: This does not fix it. Chef still sees the `depends 'ohai'` and tries to compile the cookbook

Comment: depends cannot be made to be conditional based on the chef version.  that if statement will actually be evaluated on the workstation that uploads the cookbook.  if conditional include_recipe works, use that (but see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19516079/506908 for better syntax to check the running chef version).  if ohai blows up in a library on 12.4 there is no solution short of upgrading off 12.4 or forking the ohai cookbook.